# How do I split a string, breaking at a limit n length?

Tags: javascript

I have this string

```
It's important to remember that this function does NOT replace newlines 
with <br> tags. Rather, it inserts a <br> tag before each newline, but 
it still preserves the newlines themselves! This caused problems for me 
regarding a function I was writing -- I forgot the newlines were still 
being preserved.
```

Using JavaScript, what is the fastest way to parse this into

```
var string1 = "It's important to remember that this function does ...";
```

This means, I want limit string that has n length and in the end it has '...'.

Help me.

Comment: `I want limit string that has n length` can you elaborate a bit further with an example.

Comment: `str = str.substring(0,limit)+"&hellip;")` - this may break at `<b` so please update your question with more information

Comment: how about using CSS with `ellipsis` http://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/jwsj504o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to cut words in the middle:

```js
    function shortener(s, n){
    
        var ret = "";
        if(s.charAt(n) !== " "){
            var fullWords = s.substring(0, n).split(" ").length - 1;
            ret = s.split(" ").splice(0, fullWords).join(" ");
        }
        else{
            ret = s.substring(0, n);
        }
        return ret + " ...";
    }
    var s = "It's important to remember that this function does NOT replace newlines  with <br> tags. Rather, it inserts a <br> tag before each newline, but  it still preserves the newlines themselves! This caused problems for me regarding a function I was writing -- I forgot the newlines were still being preserved. ";

    console.log(shortener(s, 16));
    console.log(shortener(s, 4));
    console.log(shortener(s, 80));
```

Output:

- It's important ...
- It's ...
- It's important to remember that this
  function does NOT replace newlines  with ...

Comment: I have attached a code snippet to my post so you can run it and make sure that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var shortenedString = originalString.substring(0, n) + "..."
```

It's a bit simple and will cut off words in the middle, but it does the trick.

Comment: @mplungjan: heheh yep sorry, you apparently beat me by 10 seconds ^^

Comment: But you beat Charles by 2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Use substring method from string java class. And research better. I`m sure this question has been answered a lot of times. What do you want is

```
var string1 = string0.substring(0,n);
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are using only javascript, here is polyfill taken from https://gist.github.com/timruffles/3377784

```js
var sample =`It's important to remember that this function does NOT replace newlines 
with <br> tags. Rather, it inserts a <br> tag before each newline, but 
it still preserves the newlines themselves! This caused problems for me 
regarding a function I was writing -- I forgot the newlines were still 
being preserved.`;

var chunk = function(array,chunkSize) {
 return array.reduce(function(reducer,item,index) {
  reducer.current.push(item);
  if(reducer.current.length === chunkSize || index + 1 === array.length) {
   reducer.chunks.push(reducer.current);
   reducer.current = [];
  }
  return reducer;
 },{current:[],chunks: []}).chunks
};

var data = chunk(sample.split(/[ ]+/), 10);
data.forEach(function(line){
console.log(line.join(" "))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard JavaScript offers three `String` methods that allow you to cut your string at position n :

- [**`String.slice( begin [, end ] )`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)
- [**`String.substring( from [, to ] )`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)
- [**`String.substr( start [, length ] )`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Just use one of these methods and add `...` at the end of your result.

---

### Demo 1

```js
var myString = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
var n = 5;
var output = '';

output += myString.slice(0, n) + '...' + '\n<br>';      // Option 1
output += myString.substring(0, n) + '...' + '\n<br>';  // Option 2
output += myString.substr(0, n) + '...';                // Option 3

document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xvrkpaux/8/).

---

### Demo 2

If you want to do this often, you may want to wrap this in a function :

```js
var myString = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
var output = '';

function shorten(str, n) {
    if(n > 0) {
        return str.slice(0, n) + '...';
    }
    return '...';
}

output += shorten(myString, 20) + '\n<br>';   
output += shorten(myString, 8) + '\n<br>'; 
output += shorten(myString, 0);

document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xvrkpaux/7/).